# Best IT/back-office system hacks?

Tags: scripting, automation

Lots of people have things that their systems do for them or for their teams. Source control post-commit hooks are a standard example: have an automated build system that checks out the latest source, compiles, tests, and packages it is a back-office hack that most of us probably use.

What other cool things have you done?

Comment: The wiki police strike again!  Don't change it to wiki unless you want to.  Let others upvote or downvote based on whether they think you're contributing value, and allow those who give good answers to be rewarded.

Comment: @Davis AMEN TO THAT BROTHER! It seems like any post that is remotely likely to generate interest gets told to wikifi.  According to Jeff the wiki stuff was to prevent a very popular question from skewing rep away from technical points.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

We had one developer in our team who wasn't familiar with the concept of a subversion conflict.  He deduced that if he simply deleted all that weird stuff in his code and clicked resolve that everything was ok (i.e. knocking out all the other changes in the file....)

Regardless to say, after the 5th time this occurred, and the 5th time that I had to explain why that defect that I just closed was reoccuring, I wrote a script.

It would diff for the changes to a file to see whether the consecutive checkin deleted all the previous changes and that they were done by the nameless developer.

It would then send an email to the boss with a description of what happened, and how much work was lost during the checkin.

There was no 7th occurrence.

Answer (score 18):

We have a traffic-light that shows whether our daily build succeeds, has failed tests or simply doesn't build.

Also, we have a light bar that lights up for a few seconds whenever we receive an upload from a customer.

Comment: do you have any pictures, sounds like a fun setup

Answer (score 9):

We aren't staffed 24x7 but we have critical processes that run throughout the night.  We created an in-house alerts system to notify us of serious system issues, failed mission-critical processes, etc.  It uses text-to-speech to create a descriptive message and then connects to our automated dialer to call the appropriate people with the message.

Answer (score 4):

Working at a web design company I configured our dev server so we could see a working copy of a project in real time by a sub domain name.  So if your name was joe and you were working on project jetfuel you would go to `joe.jetfuel.test-example.com` and you could see your changes instantly without committing.

This was a simple hack that used sub domain names as a partial directory structure.  Our htdocs path looked like this `htdocs/tag/project`.  We had a script (a php app that you would access by `setup.test-example.com`) that would create a new tag name for you and checkout whatever version you wanted and call the deploy script for that project.  If it succeeded it would forward you to the new sub domain.  You could then work on this new copy by a samba share.

This worked really well for us since we always deployed to the same linux build and our projects had simple database requirements.

Our original reason for doing this was because our developers worked on all kinds of different platforms.  Besides fixing this platform problem this was awesome for viewing changes and testing.  We had all kinds of tags ranging from peoples names, trunk versions, test tags, all the way to prototypes like `jquery-menu-hack.jetfuel.test-example.com`

Now that I look back I wonder how much easier it would have been to run virtual machines.

Answer (score 4):

We had a dev working on a classic ASP site that didn't believe in source control.  The code went from his machine straight to the production box.  This lead to issues with lost changes or the inability to revert back to a stable version.  Since CruiseControl.Net has the ability to monitor a directory, I added a project that actually checked in files whenever they were copied to production.  Completely backward from CC.Net's original intent, but we didn't lose any more code.

Answer (score 4):

Put in a pre-commit hook that checks the bug comment refers to an open bug, assigned to the user doing the checkin. (SCMBug can do this).

Then to make life REALLY interesting, spell check the comments!!
The commit comment, and the one in the code. (spell is my buddy)

Run the code through a code formatter set to compayn standard; and diff it to the original: if it's not in company offical format: reject the commit.

Do a coverage test with the unit test build.

Email all mistakes/errors caused  to the development team.

I left OUT the name of the developer. They know they did it.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly hacks, but a couple of must-haves for IT dev work:

If you're using subversion, you've got to use CommitMonitor.  (http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/CommitMonitor)  It lets you monitor svn repositories for new commits & then review the new commits.  Great if you're wanting to stay on top of what your team is doing.  Particularly if you have a couple of juniors that need to be watched. ;)

Rsnapshot (http://www.rsnapshot.org/) is also invaluable - we have complete backup snapshots of our entire filesystem every four hours going back 2 years, and every day beyond that.  It's like a data cube for your filesystem!  The peace of mind this gives is pure bliss.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Hardly a hack, but back in the day, on our speedy VAX 11/730, our overnight process would print the file "BLAMMO.TXT" on the printer if something went amiss. Every morning, the first stop was the printer when coming in.

Answer (score 2):

Back in the dotCom days about 9 years ago, I had to hack a failover system between two different locations. We had a funky setup with a powerbuilder front end website, and powerbuilder managment tool. Data was stored in MSSQL 7.0. The webservers used IPX to communicate to the SQL Servers (don't ask). Anyway, I was responsbile for coming up with a failover plan.

I ended up hacking together some linux boxes, and had them run our external DNS. One at each location. We had a remote site w/ webserver, and sql server I got SQL transaction replication working over a 128k ISDN IPX connection (of all things). Then built a monitoring tool at our production site to send packets out to various upstream network handoffs. If we experienced more than 20% outage the primary site, the monitoring tool ran a perl script on the Debian box to change DNS and point to our 2ndary. Our secondary had a heartbeat w/ our primary DNS, and monitoring station. It would duplicate records unless it lost both connections then it would roll over to pointing DNS to backup location.

The primary site would shut down the SQL server at the primary location to break replication. Automated site to site failover using 128k ISDN IPX connection :)

Answer (score 0):

Back at my previous job, we had to audit many tables for data changes (inserts, updates and deletes).  Our support crew had to be able to search through this data to find changes that users made.

The temporary solution that had become semi-permanent was to store each non-select query.  However this was a large system, that the table would grow by about 1.5GB a day.

The solution I came up with was to create a script that for all tables in an external list, created the appropriate triggers that audit each table, row, column, before and after, when and by whom and store it in our new audit table.  This table grew by about 10% the size of the older version and stored much more usable data.  It enabled us to create a UI to search and view every change made to our data, without requiring any knowledge of SQL for our support team or business users.

Answer (score 0):

This is at a lesser level, but I am fairly proud of a make file I wrote for compiling code for my research. It only needs to be given your source and header file names that can take care of the rest all by itself (though it does make the one assumption that you will not be compiling any header files into objects, only source files get compiled). The other downsides are the fact that it relies on the GNU make program's second expansion feature, so I don't know if it works on other make programs. Additionally the compiler used needs to support something similar to gcc's -MM feature. Here is hoping that no one laughs at it.

```
-include prereqs.mk
HEADERS=$(SRC_DIR)/gs_lib.h $(SRC_DIR)/gs_structs.h
SOURCES=$(SRC_DIR)/main.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/gs_lib.cpp
OBJECTS=$(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(SOURCES))

release: FLAGS=$(GEN_FLAGS)$(OPT_FLAGS)
release: $(OBJECTS) prereqs.mk
    $(CXX) $(FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) $(OUTPUT_FLAG) $(EXECUTABLE) $(OBJECTS)

prereqs.mk: $(SOURCES) $(HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(DIR_FLAGS) $(MAKE_FLAG) $(SOURCES) | sed 's,\([abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_]*\).o:,\1= \\\n,' > $@

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(OBJECTS): $$($$(patsubst $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,%,$$@))
    $(CXX) $(FLAGS) $(NO_LINK_FLAG) $(OUTPUT_FLAG) $@ $(patsubst $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp,$@)
```

Obviously I dropped the definition of a number of variables, but I think it gets the idea across.
Since my coding tools and style are compatible with the requirements of this script I like to use it. All I need to do to add (a) new piece(s) of source code is add its name(s) to the appropriate variable and the rest is taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

We have Twitter accounts for many projects which tweet things like commit messages, notices from builds, failed unit tests, deployments, bug tracking activity - any kind of event associated with the project.  Running a client like Twitter Gwibber (which displays a pop-up for each new status) is a great way to stay in touch with the activity on the projects you are interested.  Using Twitter is good as you can take advantage of all the 3rd party apps - such as the iPhone clients.

Answer (score 0):

Add commit-hook check for VRML/3d-model files with absolute path to textures/images. `f:/maya/my-textures/newproject/xxxx.png` just doesn't belong on the server.

Answer (score -1):

Back in the 1993, when source control systems were really expensive and unwieldy, the company I worked about had an in-house source control built as 4DOS scripts. It wasn't as sofisticated as most current source control systems, for example it didn't have branching or integrates, but it did the basic job of supporting revisions history, checkout/checkin and rudimentary conflict resolution.